# How to identify the Default Mode Network in fMRI images?

Tags: fmri

I am relatively new to the realm of fMRI modality and the project that I am working on requires me to find the number of clusters in healthy and schizophrenic fMRI images by generating the Default Mode Network (DMN) t-maps. Is there any software available that exclusively allows me to do this? If not, is there a pipeline that I can follow in order to generate the t-maps?